# Tango / Unity: the TangoApplication resets values upon scene switch

Tags: google-project-tango

Was chasing my tail endlessly trying to figure out why the new 3D reconstruction was working in some scenes but not others, only to discover that the TangoAplication script on the Tango Manager prefab is resetting to default when I switch scenes.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior, and did you get it to stop? I am assuming that scripting the setup of this is a somewhat easy fix, but there has got to be a less time-consuming fix for this bug?

Comment: Are you using the auto connect to service check box on the Tango Manager? But even you use the check box, the settings on the manager shouldn't reset. I wonder if you are using any of don't destroy onload function?

Comment: @JasonGuo no scripting on my end in these scenes, I was just moving between example scenes and I noticed that the TangoApplication script was losing the state of checkboxes. That said I have not seen this behavior since first reported, so there may have been something screwy with my Unity session. If I find it again and am able to replicate I will put steps to reproduce on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not been able to replicate this behavior since I first experienced it so I'm marking this answered until I am able to replicate or find a cause for it.